# ggplot2: How to use variables inside expression for labeling axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to label the axis of my plot using variables within `expression` because I will add superscripts.

```
axis_label <- "some axis label"

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = axis_label
  )
```

This does not work: (I need to evaluate the variable axis_label)

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = expression(axis_label^2)
  )
```

I am using this page, it does not solve my problem:
https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/wiki/Plotmath

Comment: it displays "axis_label" without evaluating it.

Comment: I think you want `scale_y_continuous(name = bquote(.(axis_label)^2))`